# Vertically center Div with Button using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/TN6wW/3/

Trying to get the "Click" button to set the margins of the "mainImage" such that the image will be centered vertically on the page. I'm also trying to avoid jQuery if possible (I've seen jQuery solutions, but I'm a student trying to learn one thing at a time)

My final goal is to figure out how to do what the "click" button is supposed to do, except do it when I click the "next/prev" buttons (and ensure that it uses numbers from the new image and not the current image).

Comment: Good Question Erir Wolf +1 for trying to learn one thing at a time

Comment: Eric, you might want to check your fiddle... current the button you have references a function "changeMargin", but in your Javascript you have a function called "changeMargins".  Note the plurality before continuing with your solution.  Also, keep learning man, way to not try and bite off more than you can chew.

Comment: Oh! Thanks for that. I fixed it and I'll update the question, but unless I missed something else, it's still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common technique is to use top: 50% and use a negative margin-top that is half the image's height: http://jsfiddle.net/TN6wW/29/

Comment: for whatever reason, it's not working on my site. (it does work fine in the fiddle) look at: http://esw8633.cias.rit.edu/portfolio/52.php

Comment: You're not passing `changeMargins()` the id in your HTML tag. You need `onload="changeMargins('mainImage')"`

Comment: Ah! Thank you. I guess I need to learn to avoid careless mistakes as much as anything